# RxJava emit multiple errors

Tags: java, rx-java

The server I'm communicating with has an option to join multiple calls into one.
so assuming I'm joining 2..n calls into one call the reponse can retrieve 0..n  errors at once.
is there a way to emmit multiple errors in one disposable?

Comment: You can try looking into CompositeException. 
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/exceptions/CompositeException.html

Answer (score 2):

According to `Reactive Streams` contract, there is no way to call `onError()` several times for single source. When you combining multiple sources into one, that source should also satisfy described contract.

If you need so strange behavior, you can use [`Observable#onErrorReturn`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorreturn), [`Observable#onErrorResumeNext`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext) and similar operators. Using that operators, you can wrap exceptions in some class (for example, class Result(e: Exception)) and pass it through `rx` chain.